# Why does this Haskell code produce a stack overflow?

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

I'm playing around with Haskell for the first time. I wrote these three lines, expecting to get a compiler error, but typing it inside `ghci` results in a stack overflow.

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Prelude> data ImNewToHaskell = AndWhatIsThis
Prelude> instance Show ImNewToHaskell
Prelude> show AndWhatIsThis
"*** Exception: stack overflow
```

Can anyone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You didn't define the methods of the instance.  The default for `show` uses `showPrec` (via `shows`) and the default for `showPrec` uses `show`.  So you have a cyclic definition which will clearly overflow the stack eventually.  Perhaps you intended to derive an instance?

```
Prelude> data ImNewToHaskell = AndWhatIsThis deriving (Show)
Prelude> show AndWhatIsThis
"AndWhatIsThis"
```

EDIT: Clearing up any issues with `instance` and `deriving`:

When you type `instance` is means "I am going to define my own instance or leverage the type class's default code":

```
instance Show Foo where
    show Foo = "This is the string representing Foo"
```

When you type `deriving` after a data declaration then the compiler will automatically generate a sensible instance for your type:

```
data MyType = OneOrMoreConstructors deriving (Show)
```

If you, or another programmer, did not deriving a desired instance and you do not desire to write your own then you can use standalone deriving, which yields the same result as using `deriving` but on its own line likely in a different module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
deriving instance Show MyType
```

Answer (score 5):

[Newer GHC's](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7633) emits a warning there:

```
λ> data ImNewToHaskell = AndWhatIsThis
λ> instance Show ImNewToHaskell

<interactive>:108:10: Warning:
    No explicit implementation for
      either ‘showsPrec’ or ‘show’
    In the instance declaration for ‘Show ImNewToHaskell’
λ> show AndWhatIsThis
"*** Exception: stack overflow
```

As you can see, you aren't defining an implementation for methods necessary, and the [default implementations](http://git.haskell.org/packages/base.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/GHC/Show.lhs) of the methods cause infinite recursion and therefore stack overflow.

```
class  Show a  where
    showsPrec :: Int -> a -> ShowS
    show      :: a   -> String
    showList  :: [a] -> ShowS

    showsPrec _ x s = show x ++ s
    show x          = shows x ""
    showList ls   s = showList__ shows ls s

shows           :: (Show a) => a -> ShowS
shows           =  showsPrec 0
```

Comment: Notice the author is using GHC 7.6.3 which has no such warning.